What does the $\dot{H}^s$ norm measure?
For integer integers $k \geq 0$ and $p \geq 1$ the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is defined as the functions belonging to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and whose weak derivatives up to order $k$ are also in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$. When $p = 2$ we write $W^{k,2} = H^k$. By observing that differentiation is equivalent to multiplication in a Fourier basis we can equivalently define $H^k$ as the set of functions that are finite in the following norm:
$$\|u\|_{H^k}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |1+\xi|^{2k} |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi < \infty. \tag{1}$$
Allowing $k$ to now be in $\mathbb{R}$ and generalizing the above to include tempered distributions whose Fourier transform are in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ we call the above a nonhomogeneous Sobolev space.
For $s \in \mathbb{R}$ the homogenous Sobolev space $\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ can be defined (e.g. in Bahouri, Chemin, and Danchin's book) as the space of tempered distributions $u$ over $\mathbb{R}^d$, the Fourier transform of which belongs to $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and satisfies
$$\|u\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\xi|^{2s} |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi < \infty. \tag{2}$$
Qualitatively, I do not see what the homogeneous norm (2) is measuring that (1) does not. At first glance I would think it more precisely measures regularity since (2) emphasizes frequencies far from $0$. However in the Bahouri book they say that $\dot{H}^s$ and $\dot{H}^{s'}$ cannot be compared for inclusion so I don't think my intuition is correct.
On the other hand, the wonderful answer to this question about the inverse Laplacian states that it is not true that
$$(-\Delta)^{-1}: L^p(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$$
but it is true that
$$(-\Delta)^{-1}: L^p(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow \dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$$
where the definition of $\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ can be found in the question linked above. This leads me to believe that the homogeneous norm is indeed measuring regularity differently than the nonhomogeneous norm, but I don't understand how.
EDIT: I just noticed nonhomogeneous Sobolev spaces are defined as tempered distributions whose Fourier transforms belong to $L^2_{loc}$. Why do we require $L^2_{loc}$ unlike the homogenous space which requires $L^1_{loc}$?

When $s>0$, $H^s = \dot H^s \cap L^2$. The first scales like $L^p$ with $p>2$ the Sobolev exponent

@LL3.14 So can we say that homogeneous spaces measure the regularity of functions that may not be in $L^2$, whereas nonhomogeneous spaces also take the global behavior into account? Can anything be said about the case $s < 0$?

Also the constant function $u \equiv 1$ belongs to $\dot H^s(\mathbb R^d)$ but not to $L^2$ nor $H^s$.

@daw Thank you. The recurring theme I see here is that $\dot{H}^s$ does not care about the global behavior of the function (whether or not it is in $L^2$), and only cares about the function's derivatives. Is that the whole point of these homogeneous spaces?

I would say: yes, but I am not too experienced with these kind of spaces.

@daw If that's the case I would expect that an inclusion  such as $\dot{H}^{s'} \subset \dot{H}^{s}$ would exist for $s' \geq s$ but this is false.

I just noticed nonhomogeneous Sobolev spaces are defined as tempered distributions whose Fourier transforms belong to $L^2_{loc}$. Why do we require $L^2_{loc}$ unlike the homogenous space which requires $L^1_{loc}$?

This depends on the book you are reading, it is not an established standard. Both the homogeneous and non-homogeneous spaces take into account the behavior locally and at infinity. The local behavior is the same for both spaces (and implies locally $L^p$, $p=2^*>2$) but the global behavior is different : $L^2$ integrability for the non-homogeneous, which is stronger than the $L^p$ global behavior of the homogeneous.

This explains that there are no inclusions, the higher the $s$, the more local regularity but the less global decay ... like $L^p$ spaces actually. In the graph of Sobolev spaces http://laurent-lafleche.perso.math.cnrs.fr/images/GagNir.svg, the homogeneous spaces correspond to red lines while non-homogeneous are triangles ($H^s-L^2-L^p$)

@LL3.14 My understanding of these spaces is that the homogeneous norm completely ignores the global behavior of the function (it doesn't involve the function's $L^p$ norm, only its derivatives) whereas the non-homogeneous norm measures its global (integrability) and local (regularity) behavior. From this picture I naively would expect that there is an inclusion for homogeneous norms which I know is incorrect. How can one see that there is no inclusion for homogeneous spaces like there is for non-homogeneous ones?
